# AWS S3 action to permit redirect edits in website enabled bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to allow our web developer to change redirect rules on a specific website enabled bucket, using AWS console.

What policy permissions would I have to add? They can manage objects in the bucket already, but I am not sure what specific action to add to let them change redirect XML.

Here's the current policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::staging.site.com",
            "arn:aws:s3:::staging.site.com/*",
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

All web site hosting-related configuration is on the `/?website` subresource, which (technically speaking) is completely overwritten, each time it is changed.  This includes...

> [...] website configuration information such as the file name of the index document and any redirect rules.
>
> This `PUT` operation requires the `S3:PutBucketWebsite` permission.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html